# Typescript and Extending kendo DataSource

Tags: kendo-ui, typescript

I'm using KendoUI and typescript in my application and i want convert this code to typescript:

```
var customDataSource= kendo.data.DataSource.extend({

    init: function (options) {

        kendo.data.DataSource.fn.init.call(this, options);
   }
});
```

But typescript can't convert and display error in this line:

```
 kendo.data.DataSource.fn.init.call(this, options);
```

what is wrong?(I'm using kendo.all.d.ts)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## A simpler quick fix:

Just use `any`:

```
(<any>kendo.data.DataSource).fn.init.call(this, options);
```

## Complex better fix :

TypeScript cannot infer that `init` is now a member function of `kendo.data.DataSource`. Depending upon what the type of `kendo.data.DataSource` is you can tell typescript about it. I am assuming the type is something like `kendo.data.IDataSource`

```
declare module kendo{
   module data{
       interface IDataSource{
           init:Function;
       }
   }
}
```